# Not able to mount Windows 2012 Server network drives

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, shared-folders

Up until recently my fstab file was able to mount file shares from a windows 2012 Server without any issues. Sometime within the past two weeks the shares no longer mount. I now get the error `mount error(5): Input/output error`.

Interestingly enough, there are other shares being mapped in the same file from a Windows 2016 Server without any issues.

I've confirmed that the windows account is **not** locked out; still experienced the same issue.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Where am I going wrong? I'm trying to mount using SMB 2.1 (as per the fstab file).

Running Ubuntu 18.04

EDIT: All,

I HATE that this is the answer (but it is) - I upgraded the two servers running server 2012 to server 2019 and the issue is resolved. I have no idea why as I did not make ANY config changed on the linux side. My shares now successfully mount.

Good luck and God speed to anyone else who reads this and winds up in the same boat - it was easier in my small homelab to upgrade than to continue to try and figure out why it wasn't working

Comment: Have you tried cifs vers=1.0

Comment: SMB v1 is disabled (as it should be) on the Windows Server. This was working with vers=2.1 in my fstab up until about a week or two ago.

Comment: All,

I HATE that this is the answer (but it is) - I upgraded the two servers running server 2012 to server 2019 and the issue is resolved. I have no idea why as I did not make ANY config changed on the linux side. My shares now successfully mount.

Good luck and God speed to anyone else who reads this and winds up in the same boat - it was easier in my small homelab to upgrade than to continue to try and figure out why it wasn't working